# mount a CIFS share with full RW access

Tags: mount, samba, shared-folders, cifs

This is the first time I'm trying this. I would like to mount a shared windows network drive on my linux server. following command is doing the job but it is just the read access :

```
 mount -t cifs -o username=myuser,domain=ad009,uid=myuserid,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,gid=1001 //windowsShearedDrive/data/OF /home/myuser/of
```

In `of` folder on my linux running the `ls -l` returns :

```
total 4096
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 xxxxxxxx shiny  1933 Dec 18  2015 Archive_OF.lnk
drwxrwxrwx. 2 xxxxxxxx shiny     0 Jan 30 00:34 BEL-00003
drwxrwxrwx. 2 xxxxxxxx shiny     0 Jan 14  2019 BEL-00047
drwxrwxrwx. 2 xxxxxxxx shiny     0 Jan 14  2019 CHN-00707
drwxrwxrwx. 2 xxxxxxxx shiny     0 Mar 20  2015 CHN-00708
...
```

So I am unable to write anything in that mounted drive. Is the problem in the `file_mode` and `dir_mode` ?
instead of 0777 I have tried the 0700 for both but still no write access ! and by the way what are the valid options for `file_mode` and `dir_mode` ?

The following is my linux os /version info :

```
cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.5 (Maipo)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VARIANT="Server"
VARIANT_ID="server"
VERSION_ID="7.5"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.5:GA:server"
HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"

REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.5
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7.5"
```

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: I have the same problem, have you figured out a solution?

Comment: Ok, I take it back, file_mode=0777 and dir_mode=0777 did the job for me. Here is the full fstab record: `//server/share /mnt/ cifs username=smb_user,credentials=/etc/fstab.password,rw,auto,nofail,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0` - Ubuntu 18.04.4

Comment: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68079/mount-cifs-network-drive-write-permissions-and-chown
This worked for me with the same problem - can't write into the CIFS directory: mount.cifs //192.168.0.100/<remotedir> <mylocaldir> -o username=<myuser>,uid=1000,gid=1000,vers=2.0

Answer (score 4):

Use the `rw` option to enable read/write access. This would make your command `mount -t cifs -o rw,username=myuser,domain=ad009,uid=myuserid,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,gid=1001 //windowsShearedDrive/data/OF /home/myuser/of` This should work, assuming your user has write permissions on that samba share.

Comment: Nope ! that does not work and yes I do have read and write access on the sheared drive

Comment: Try using file and dir mode of 777 rather than 0777.

Comment: Oh ! come on ! you don't have to reply if you have no idea !!!

Comment: It works with file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777. (or other desired mode)